# Is there any direct way to check the date format column by column in python(using datetime)?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have a date column in a df. Now I want to check if it is matching with a particular format or not by doing column by column. I did it row by row but it takes a lot of time to run. I want to know if there is a way for checking the column at once the column might contain nulls or a different format of a date. Although I tried doing it column-wise if there is one record that is not matching it goes into except. So, how can we do that?

code:

```
df=
    Date
0  12-22-2020
1  22-12-2020
3  22122020
4
5  02-22-2020
formatt='%m-%d-%Y'
try:
    datetime = dt.strptime(str(df['Date']), formatt) 
    print(datetime )                                
except ValueError:
    print('error')
```

This gives: `'error'`

It's giving as a whole. But I want the accepted records to be displayed. How do we do it?

Expected output:

```
datetime =
 Date
0  12-22-2020
4
5  02-22-2020
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use pandas `to_datetime` function with `errors='coerce'` and keep lines correctly converted and lines that were null in the initial column.

Code could be

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce', format='%m-%d-%Y')
dates = dates[(~dates.isna())|df['Date'].isnull()]
```

It gives:

```
0   2020-12-22
4          NaT
5   2020-02-22
```