# How do we convert a date into a particular format using DATETIME(python)?

Tags: python, dataframe, date, datetime

I have a date column in a df. I want to check if the formats are valid or not and then convert it into a particular date format. TO convert I used `datetime.strptime` but it says that I can't convert as the DateTime doesn't match the format but I gave the exact same format of the column which is checked and converted to a default format using `to_datetime`. Why am I getting the error what is the best way to convert a column all at once to a particular date format?

code:

```
df=
    Date
0  12-22-2020
1  22-12-2020
3  22122020
4
5  02-22-2020
```

checking if valid dates or not:

```
c=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],errors='coerce')
later I get this:
c:
0   2020-12-22
4          NaT
5   2020-02-22
```

Now I want to convert this into %m-%d-%Y format.

```
c=c.to_frame()
c=c.dropna()
datetime.datetime.strptime(str(c['Date']),'%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
```

I get error as below:

```
ValueError: time data '0 2020-12-22\n5   2020-02-22 Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

Though it is same format why am I getting this error?

Comment: considering [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66784347/is-there-any-direct-way-to-check-the-date-format-column-by-column-in-pythonusin), what problem are you trying to solve? all date strings in your example are *valid*, it's just that the day sometimes comes first, sometimes second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['12-22-2020','22-12-2020','22122020',np.nan, '02-22-2020']})
```

you can do :

```
df1 = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],errors='coerce')
```

which gives:

```
0   2020-12-22
1   2020-12-22
2          NaT
3          NaT
4   2020-02-22
```

you see that you have two Nan now as one is from yours and the other is a string `22122020`. Now if you do

```
df1.dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

you get:

```
0    12/22/2020
1    12/22/2020
2           NaN
3           NaN
4    02/22/2020
```

which is the format you want.

Comment: note that `pandas` by default uses `dayfirst=False`, so it is assumed that the day comes second. `'22-12-2020'` just happens to work because `22` is not a valid month. But that is evaluated *per entry*  of the series - so kind of error-prone if not specified in the first place.